# Перебор и вывод элементов словаря map

Tags: c++, map

Есть словарь

```
map<string, long long> a;`
```

Надо вывести его элементы. Пробовал такой способ:

```
for (auto now : s)
{
    cout << now.first << " " << now.second << "\n";
}
```

Какие способы есть еще, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А чем этот способ не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto [first, second] : s)
{
    cout << first << " " << second << "\n";
}
```

можно также написать перегрузку оператора ввода

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<string, long long> p)
{
    out << p.first << " " << p.second <<  "\n";
    return out;
}
```

и потом использовать, например, так:

```
map<string, long long>::const_iterator It = a.begin();
while (It != a.end())
    cout << *It++;
```

Comment: этот вариант тоже не сработал

Comment: у вас компилятор старой версии